# Access-Control-Allow-Origin when calling WCF REST Service from jQuery and JSON

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, rest

I have the following code.

**WCF REST method**

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "Account")]
    [OperationContract]
    string GetUniqueLoginId();
```

**Client Side Call**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: serviceURL + 'Account',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    success: app.onGetUniqueId,
    error: app.onAjaxError
 });
```

When I use IE (11), it works perfectly by returning a unique id. But when I use chrome, it gives me the following error.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin   'http://localhost:5553' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How to resolve the issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the WCF service you request is in a different origin than the application which invokes it, and hence restricted by ["Same Origin policy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) .You will have to use JSONP( for which the service has to support jsonp) or CORS ( the server side should add the CORS headers allowing your origin)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable CORS on a service hosted on IIS or IIS Express by adding the following configuration in the web config file.

```
<system.webServer>  

<httpProtocol>  
  <customHeaders>  
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />  
  </customHeaders>  
</httpProtocol>
 ...
```

By setting it to *, we are allowing requests from any origin to access the service.